# onUpgrade() of Android database called sporadically

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an older app which stores data into its local sqlite database. Now I want to update the schema of this database.

I know I can use the onUpgrade()-method and a static version-variable to invoke onUpgrade(). I also know that onUpgrade() is only called if "getReadableDatabase()" or "getWritableDatabase"() is called.

But even though I do make such a call, and even though I change the version number, onUpgrade is only called about every second time when I change the version.

For example:

Version #2 --> #3: onUpgrade is called

Version #3 --> #4: onUpgrade is not called
and so on...

How can that be?

Comment: If the database file already has the requested version, `onUpgrade()` is not called. Please post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: How are you asserting that it's not called when you expect it to be? A breakpoint? A LogCat message? Could you post your update code?

Comment: @Ben Pearson I use a LogCat message when onUpgrade is called.

Comment: It works for everybody else. Post your code!

Comment: @laalto For testing purposes, I am changing the database version every  time I build the app - onUpgrade() still only gets called about every second time.

Comment: @CL. I have another app where it also works, but for some reason it doesn't for this one...I'll update my questin soon.